# Group values from a parameter list in a loop according to the prefix of the parameter

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am fetching a param list from my jsp which I need to identify according to the prefix so that I can set the values in my entity class.

The parameter names looks like the below:

```
 List<String> reqParamNames = Arrays.asList("1_component_role", "2_component_role", "3_component_role",
            "4_component_role", "1_survey_wt", "2_survey_wt", "3_survey_wt", "4_survey_wt",     "1dynaGroup1", "1component_role1", "1wt1", "2dynaGroup1", "2component_role1", "2wt1", "3dynaGroup1",
            "3component_role1", "3wt1", "4dynaGroup1", "4component_role1", "4wt1");
```

Now, from the above list, I need to get the param according to the prefix, i.e.1,2,3,4 etc. Once grouped correctly, I would need to set it to my Entity class so that I can save the parameters in my table using Hibernate.

I am unable to set the values for the dynamic table.

```
        @RequestMapping(value = { "dynamicSettings/persist" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveComponents(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, 
      Model model) {

    LOG.debug("Entering persist area :: ");
    Locale locale = LocaleUtil.getLocale();
    // ToDo: validation for form

    //For dynamic tables
        List<String> reqParamNames = (List<String>) Collections.list((Enumeration<String>)request.getParameterNames());         

        for(int i =0; i < reqParamNames.size(); i++){

            System.out.println("Param names are {} ::"+ reqParamNames.get(i));

            String paramName = reqParamNames.get(i);

            Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*").matcher(paramName);
            if (m.matches()) {
              System.out.println("Number ::" +m.group(1)); // Need to comment/remove this post development
              }

            System.out.println("ParamNumber ::" +""+m.group(1));
            String attributeValue = request.getParameter(paramName);
            System.out.println("Param Name ::"+paramName+"::: Attribute value ::"+attributeValue);

            DynamicComponentSettings dynamicSettings = new DynamicComponentSettings();  
            if( i == paramNumber){
            String group_type        = request.getParameter("groupType"+i); 
            String component_role    = request.getParameter("component_role"+i);
            String survey_weight      = request.getParameter("wt"+i);

            System.out.println("Group Type ::"+group_type+ "::Component Role::" +component_role+ "::Survey Weight::"+survey_weight);

                if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(group_type) && StringUtils.isEmpty(component_role)&&!StringUtils.isEmpty(survey_weight)){                                           
                    Double survey_wt = Double.parseDouble(survey_weight);
                        dynamicSettings.setSurvey_wt(survey_wt);                            
                        dynamicSettings.setGroup_type(group_type);      
                        dynamicSettings.setComponent_role(component_role);
                    }               
                }
            dynamicComponentService.saveDynamicComponents(dynamicSettings);
        }

        **//For concrete table**    
        List<DynamicComponentSettings> resultList = dynamicComponentService.loadAllDynamicComponents();

            for(DynamicComponentSettings component : resultList)
            {               
                String _survey_wt = request.getParameter(component.getPk1().toString() + "survey_wt");
                String _groupRoleType = request.getParameter(component.getPk1().toString() + "group_type");
                String _componentRole = request.getParameter(component.getPk1().toString() + "component_role");

                if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(_survey_wt) && StringUtils.isEmpty(_groupRoleType)&&!StringUtils.isEmpty(_componentRole)){

                Double survey_wt = Double.parseDouble(_survey_wt);
                    component.setSurvey_wt(survey_wt);  
                    component.setGroup_type(_groupRoleType);
                    component.setComponent_role(_componentRole);
                }

            dynamicComponentService.saveDynamicComponents(component);
    }

    return "redirect:" + "some url";
  }
```

The concrete table works correctly, i.e. saving values correctly.

**Entity class**

```
            <package declaration>
            <imports>

            @Entity
            @Table(name = "dynamic_components")
            public class DynamicComponentSettings {

                /** The pk1. */
                @Id
                @SequenceGenerator(name = "dynamic_components_seq", sequenceName = "dynamic_components_seq", allocationSize = 1)
                @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "dynamic_components_seq")


                private Long pk1;

                private String group_type;
                private String component_role;
                private Double survey_wt;

                <getters and setters>
            }
```

Please provide your inputs and provide guidance as how to save the dynamic table values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out the problems and fix it. There are multiple problems in that code sample. For eg. the loops are incorrect, the approach to match with the main loop was horribly wrong.

I had to get the prefix and suffix for each item, loop correctly[i.e. first get the suffix and prefix of the table and then based on suffix match, iterate through the prefix like rows] and put each dynamic table data with suffix being the key and prefix+data+suffix being the values into a Map containing linked lists. After that, I had to loop again through the Map containing the lists to set the values to my entity class correctly.

Please pardon me for not posting the code again as the method is quite long and may not be of much help. In any case, if someone does want to see how this was solved, please let me know.

Thanks for your time.